# foreach loop in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to output an array like so:

```
durations&quot;:[{&quot;months&quot;:&quot;36&quot;},{&quot;months&quot;:&quot;48&quot;}],&quot;duration_default&quot;:&quot;60&quot;,&quot;insurance_factor&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;lease_factor&quot;:&quot;0.4637&quot;,&quot;create_fee&quot;:&quot;2500
```

The array is multidimensional like this:

```
Array ( [durations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [months] => 36 ) [1] => Array ( [months] => 48 ) ) [duration_default] => 60 [insurance_factor] => 0 [lease_factor] => 44 [create_fee] => 2500 ) )
```

I've tried this:

```
foreach ($post_fields as $key=>$item){

    echo "&quot;$key&quot; : &quot;$item&quot;, ";
  
}
```

But end up with this:

```
data-calc="{"durations" : "Array", "duration_default" : "60", "insurance_factor" : "0.9909", "lease_factor" : "44", "create_fee" : "2500", "frequency" : "month", "min_price" : "2222", "margins" : "Array",
```

How can I extract the nested arrays?

Comment: _"I'm trying to output an array like so:"_ - although that string appears to end abruptly in a way that doesn't make much sense, I think what you actually want to do here, is provide a JSON-encoded data object as the value of an HTML attribute? Then you should _not_ try and assemble the syntax yourself - use `json_encode`, and either use single quotes as the attribute delimiter, or apply `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

it was JSON so try this, `$post_fields = json_decode($post_fields , true);`

```
foreach($post_fields as $key=>$item){
   echo $item;}
```